# understanding top n tfidf features in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to understand the `TfidfVectorizer` of `scikit-learn` a bit better. The  following code has two documents `doc1 = The car is driven on the road`,`doc2 = The truck is driven on the highway`. By calling `fit_transform` a vectorized matrix of tf-idf weights is generated.

According to the `tf-idf` value matrix, shouldn't `highway,truck,car` be the top words instead of `highway,truck,driven` as `highway = truck= car= 0.63 and driven = 0.44`?

```
#testing tfidfvectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np

tn = ['The car is driven on the road', 'The truck is driven on the highway']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer= lambda x:x.split(),stop_words = 'english')
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(tn)

feature_array = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) #list of features
print(feature_array)
print(response.toarray())

sorted_features = np.argsort(response.toarray()).flatten()[:-1] #index of highest valued features
print(sorted_features)

#printing top 3 weighted features
n = 3
top_n = feature_array[sorted_features][:n]
print(top_n)
```

```
['car' 'driven' 'highway' 'road' 'truck']
[[0.6316672  0.44943642 0.         0.6316672  0.        ]
 [0.         0.44943642 0.6316672  0.         0.6316672 ]]
[2 4 1 0 3 0 3 1 2]
['highway' 'truck' 'driven']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the result, the tf-idf matrix is indeed giving a higher score to `highway`,`truck`,`car` (and `truck`):

```
tn = ['The car is driven on the road', 'The truck is driven on the highway']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(tn)
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

pd.DataFrame(response.toarray(), columns=terms)

        car    driven   highway      road     truck
0  0.631667  0.449436  0.000000  0.631667  0.000000
1  0.000000  0.449436  0.631667  0.000000  0.631667
```

What's wrong is the further check you do by flattening the array. To get the top scores accross all rows, you could instead do something like:

```
max_scores = response.toarray().max(0).argsort()
np.array(terms)[max_scores[-4:]]
array(['car', 'highway', 'road', 'truck'], dtype='<U7')
```

Where the highest scores are the feature_names that have a `0.63` score in the dataframe.

Comment: what does `max(0) ` mean in `response.toarray().max(0)` ?

Comment: You're getting the maximum values for each column. That is the axis argument `ndarray.max(axis=0)` @afsara_ben